# About the amount of energy transferred by the virtual photon in the particular process

Tags: particle-physics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering-cross-section

Suppose the process 
$$
\tag 1 x+y\to x+y+z,
$$ 
where $x,y$ are some electrically charged particle (for definiteness, let identify $x$ as a spin 1/2 fermion) and $z$ is another particle. The process goes through the $\bar{x}\gamma_{\mu}xA^{\mu}$ vertex, i.e., it includes the sub-diagram of "emission" of the virtual photons by the $x$ particle. Corresponding amplitude takes the form
$$
\tag 2 M = \bar{x}(k_{1})\gamma_{\mu}x(p_{1})D^{\mu\nu}(k_{1}-p_{1})...,
$$ 
where $D_{\mu\nu}(p)$ is the photon's propagator. Finally, at y's lab frame the $x$ particle is ultrarelativistic.

I'm interested in the case when the outgoing $y$ and $z$ particles carry the most of the energy of the incoming $x$ particle. I would like to know what is the probability for the such case. Naively, from $(2)$ I expect that the process $(1)$ is the most efficient when $(k_{1} - p_{1})^{2}$ is minimal. But this requires that $p_{1} \approx k_{1}$, which, in its turn, means that the amount $x$ of the energy of transferred by the virtual photon line is small, $x\ll 1$; numerically this is expressed in soft QED singularity. However, I'm not sure in this statement and would like to know other more or less quantitative arguments about this.

Could you please help me?

Comment: What stops you from computing the scattering amplitude yourself and just *looking at* whether or not it is higher for certain values of $k$ or $p$?

Comment: @ACuriousMind : I'm looking for a simple argument allowing to answer on my question, without the direct computation of the squared amplitude.